# list index out of range sorting highest to lowest

Tags: python, sorting

```
file = open("1.txt")
classj = (file.readlines())
s = []
for line in sorted(classj):
    classj = (line.rstrip())
    classa = (classj.split("-"))#sort
    score = int(classa[1])
    name = (classa[0])
    s.append( (name,score) )
s.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1])
for x in s:
    print(x[0],"-",x[1])
```

I have got the content of a text file in which I have scores in which I need to sort from high to low but it originally printed only the scores but now I get the message list index out of range

Comment: What if there's no "-" in the string? Will you have elements in the resulted list?..

Comment: Add the contents of the file you are using in the question

Answer (score -1):

Your file has some lines, with no `-` in it. Perhaps an empty line?

You can ignore empty lines, or you can ignore lines with no `'-'`:

```
with open("1.txt") as inp:
    s = []
    for line in inp:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        try:
            name, score = line.split('-')
        except ValueError:
            print("Warning! Ignore line: %s" % line)
        else:
            s.append(name, int(score))
s.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1])
for name, score in s:
    print(name,"-",score)
```